# Run gitlab runner pipeline on merge requests when origin branch name has a specific name

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We create new branches from `develop` branch that starts with `hotfix/bla_bla` or `feature/bla_bla`. Then, we merge them back into develop branch. On merge requests, I would like to run a job only when we merge feature branches into develop branch. Something like:

```
job:
stage: test
only:
 refs:
 - develop && "when a branch which starts with 'feature/' is merged into develop"
```

How could I achieve this in .gitlab-ci.yml file or using a .sh file?

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but you potentially can use a combination of [pipelines for merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html) and the [CI Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`.

For example, something like:

```
job:
  stage: test
  only:
   refs:
     - merge_requests
     - develop
   variables:
     - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "feature/*"
```